# Filling array with integer values

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] getRandomPermutationOfIntegers(int size) {
      T[] data = (T[])new Comparable[size]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          data[i] = i;
      }
      // shuffle the array
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          int temp;
          int swap = i + (int) ((size - i) * Math.random());
          temp = data[i];
          data[i] = data[swap];
          data[swap] = temp;
      }
      return data;
  }
```

which permutes an array of integers and return them. I want to fill the array with int values but am getting error in the two for() loops since T is different from int.

How do i fix them to make them work?

Comment: why are you reinventing the wheel - `Collections` has a `shuffle(List)` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Integer wrapper instead of the primitive int.